# Why does this work as a WQL query?

Tags: wmi, wql

I'm writing a Powershell script and am querying the local DNS resource for both CNAME and A records matching specific criteria (specifically against HP servers). Using full administrator access rights using WQL against the root\MicrosoftDNS provider, I was presented with 0 records for the following:

```
select * from MicrosoftDNS_ResourceRecord where TextRepresentation like '%sql%'
```

However, negating a negation works.

```
select * from MicrosoftDNS_ResourceRecord where NOT(NOT(TextRepresentation like '%sql%'))
```

Why? Am I going insane?

The full query is:

```
select * from MicrosoftDNS_ResourceRecord where NOT (ContainerName like '..%' OR OwnerName like '%ilo%') AND (__CLASS = 'MicrosoftDNS_AType' OR __CLASS = 'MicrosoftDNS_CNAMEType') AND NOT(NOT(TextRepresentation like '%sql%'))
```

Comment: Just a hunch but do the records that get pulled back have `NULL` for `TextRepresentation`?

Comment: Unfortunately, while testing under wbemtest, I receive a 0x80041001 (Generic failure) error message for: select * from MicrosoftDNS_ResourceRecord where TextRepresentation IS NULL

Comment: What about the records you get from your full query? I mean your queries are pulling back records right? What are their fields like?

Comment: Yes, records are received as intended (~1000 records against production), as if the double negatives were not put in. I have further tested it by installing DNS service on a new server with only one zone with an A and a CNAME record. The fields are what a normal WQL query would return like in either case in wbemtest. Example:
instance of MicrosoftDNS_AType
{
 ContainerName = "xxx";
 DnsServerName = "xxx";
 DomainName = "xxx";
 IPAddress = "1.2.3.4";
 OwnerName = "xxx";
 RecordClass = 1;
 RecordData = "1.2.3.4";
 TextRepresentation = "xxx IN A 1.2.3.4";
 Timestamp = 0;
 TTL = 900;
};